# vk получение токена по логину и паролю

Tags: javascript, c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу windows приложение на с# для работы с vk api.
С помощью запросов перехожу на ссылки, парсю данные со страницы. Дошел до последней страницы получения разрешений приложения.
То есть нужно программно нажать кнопку "*Разрешить*".
Такой запрос шлёт браузер и такой же примерно запрос должно моё приложение

```
POST https://login.vk.com/?act=grant_access&client_id=4721061&settings=999999&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.vk.com%2Fblank.html&response_type=token&direct_hash=7e31b8326685a684bb&token_type=0&v=&state=&display=wap&ip_h=код&hash=хэш&https=1 HTTP/1.1

Cookie: remixlang=0; h=1; s=1; l=мойИДстраницы; p=6874c73330f835d27ce00b01f0f83f0ab005639e8dd15d8aa5d27; remixsid=a1dfe7f0eaa70fb1sa1dd18f5212f2ded055888dfe7f070fb1df6; remixsslsid=1
```

Не понимаю, как браузер вычисляет куку. Ключевыми являются `l` и `p`.
Первая просто парсится со страницы. Подозреваю, что `p` вычисляется манипуляциями с текущей датой с помощью javascript здесь

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
(function(k,a,d,e,f){function l(){var c=function(){var b=!1;try{b=new XMLHttpRequest}catch(a){try{b=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(d){try{b=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(c){b=!1}}}return b?e:f}(),g=function(){var b=k.createElement("div");b.innerHTML='<input type="file" />';b=b.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];return"file"!=b.type||b.disabled?f:e}(),h="ontouchstart"in a?e:f,m;try{m=typeof navigator.geolocation!==d?e:typeof a.google!==d&&typeof google.gears!==d?e:typeof device!==d&&typeof device.getServiceObject!==d?e:typeof Mojo!==d&&"Mojo.Service.Request"!==typeof Mojo.Service.Request?e:f}catch(p){m=f}var l=function(b){try{var d=a.Audio?new Audio:k.createElement("audio");if(d.canPlayType&&d.canPlayType(b)&&"no"!=d.canPlayType(b))return e}catch(c){}return f}("audio/mpeg"),n=function(b){try{for(var a=k.createElement("div"),c=0,g=["webkit","Moz","ms","O",""],h=g.length;c<h;c++){var l=g[c],m=l?l+b:b.toLowerCase();if(typeof a.style[m]!==d)return e}return f}catch(n){return f}}("Transform");return c+g+h+m+l+n+((a.XMLHttpRequest||a.XDomainRequest)&&(a.FormData||a.FileReader&&(a.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.sendAsBinary||a.ArrayBuffer&&a.Uint8Array&&(a.MozBlobBuilder||a.WebKitBlobBuilder||a.BlobBuilder)))?e:f)}var c=a.screen,g=c.width||0,c=c.height||0,n=a.devicePixelRatio||1,p=(k.cookie.match(/(^|;\s+)remixmdevice=([^;]+)/)||[])[2]||"",h=p.split("/");p&&g==h[0]&&c==h[1]&&7==h[3].length||(g=[g,c,n,l()].join("/"),k.cookie="remixmdevice=; expires="+(new Date(0)).toUTCString()+"; path=/",k.cookie="remixmdevice="+g+"; expires="+(new Date((new Date).getTime()+7776E6)).toUTCString()+"; path=/; domain=.vk.com",location.replace(location.toString()))})(document,window,"undefined","!","-");(function(a,d){var c=a.hash||"",b=c.substr(2);"#/"==c.substr(0,2)&&!d&&(b.match(/^\/*(away|login)(\.php)?([^a-z0-9\.]|$)/)&&(b=""),a.replace(a.protocol+"//"+a.host+"/"+b))})(location,1);setTimeout(function(){!location.hash&&window.scrollTo(0,/android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)?1:0)},0);
//-->
</script>
```

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1wiyixqm)

Но я совсем не понимаю этого алгоритма.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще этот геморрой? Для получения токена достаточно один раз вручную подтвердить разрешение. Вы же не регистрируете для каждого сеанса работы с API новое приложение.

Comment: Если вы работаете с vk API, почему вам понадобилось парсить страницы и разгадывать выдачу cookie?

Comment: [Авторизация происходит](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile) в браузере, и вашему приложению нужно получить адресную строку после завершения авторизации (там будет `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html?access_token=...`). Так что используйте браузерный компонент, и не парьтесь с куки.

Comment: @dunduk недостаточно. Каждый раз запрашивает.

Comment: Значит, что-то делаете не так. Мои токены работают уже второй год :) Да и подумайте: вам знакомы такие приложения, которые бы запрашивали разрешения каждый раз при тычках в API?

Comment: @dunduk я имел ввиду, что каждый раз при получении токена. Понятное дело что он один раз только получится. Бессрочный токен можно и в браузере получить. Но меня интересует это решение проблемы.

Comment: Решение проблемы было официальное, но оно исчезло из API полгода-год назад. И правильно. Какие бы вы попытки не делали сейчас - они всё равно будут временными, и будут быстро устаревать. Потому что контакт прикрывает и будет прикрывать все лазейки для этого.

Comment: @Sergiks я хочу чтобы пользователь ввёл в форму логин и пароль, и приложение на основе этого получило токен. VK не разрешает такую политику для любого приложения. Отсюда такие танцы с куками. Или использоание браузерного компонента позволяет решить эту проблему?

Comment: Но ведь [есть](https://github.com/vknet/vk/blob/master/VkNet/Utils/VkAuthorization.cs) фреймворки, которые так делают

Comment: Плохая практика: требовать логин-пароль там, где они не требуются. Для чего потребовалась именно такая схема авторизации?

Браузер, вк, согласие дать доступ, редирект на `/blank.html` с нужным вам `access_token` в адресной строке. Копируйте его вручную или программно.